# find sed regex for {}, ignoring the string in it

Tags: sed

in a `text` file (on linux system) I have this string:

`O\WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{Windows Fabrik}\FIM{Forefront Identity Manager(Benutzer)}\EXTRA{}`

Now, I want to replace the `O\WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{Windows Fabrik}`, but I don't know what is standing in `{}`. It could be empty or text in it.

I try this, but without success:

`sed -e 's/O\\WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{[a-zA-Z0-9]}/O\\WIFI{}/g'`

And that must be the Result:

`O\WIFI{}\FIM{Forefront Identity Manager(Benutzer)}\EXTRA{}`

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use the delimiter as end of your pattern, here it is `}` so take a class excluding this, any occurrence than your delimiter with `[^}]*}`

```
sed -e 's/O\\WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{[^}]*}/O\\WIFI{}/g' YourFile
```

Comment: Thanks, it will be sucessful, but what is, if I want to have this result:

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{[^}]*}/WIFI{}/g' <filename>`

Comment: you don't need to replace 0\ as you want it in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it will be sucessful, but what is, if I want to have this result:

```
O\WIFI{}\EXTRA{}.
```

It doesn't matter if I do this:

```
sed -e 's/O\\WIN_INFRASTRUKTUR{[^}]*}\\FIM{[^}]*}/O\\WIFI{}/g'
```

than I get only this result: `O\WIFI{}`

Comment: remove the `g` option a the end, there is only 1 occurrence (is there more ?)

Comment: I need the g at the end, because there is more in the file